# Lag of Variable in Panel Cross Section in R

Tags: r

As explained in the subject, I am facing a problem by creating a new lagged variable.

Situation: I have a data sample for 214 countries between 1960 and 2010 and several variables. One of the relevant variables for my analysis is the number of patents. For a certain analysis, I'd like to create a new variable that lags the current one 2, 5, and 10 years.

I thought the creation of the variable will be easy, but I am using the following code, I end up with a new variable, but it is just a copy of the original one. Do you have any idea? The problem here is that I want to create those lags only for the specific country groups.

```
df10 <- df10 %>%
  group_by(countryname) %>%
  mutate(lpat_uspt2_l = lag(lpat_uspt2, k = 5))
```

[Picture Data Set after creating the lagged variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jUNs.png)

Looking forward to any idea! Cheers.

Comment: Is your data a time series? `lag()` from `stats` works on a time series (and shifts the time base). If you want `dplyr` `lag` you may need `dplyr::lag` and use `n = 5` instead of `k = 5`. Instead of an image, can you share a sample of your data? If you can, use `dput(head(df10))` and edit your question with the results.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Was just the wrong lag function